# R, grepl, searching for a substring

Tags: r, grepl

This might look like a repeat question but I've searched **Stackoverflow** for hours and I've tried all that I could find but this wasn't solved. 
I have a character array with `.xlsx` files and I need to remove the ones with `~$` at the beginning of the file name, e.g.

> ~$MS_LM CASH.xlsx

But `grepl` returns false even for `grepl(ch[1],"MS")`, let alone special characters.

Answer (score 1):

The `$` is a regex metacharacter and needs to be escaped with backslash to use it literally in a pattern with `grepl()`:

```
grepl("\\$MS", ch[1])
```

Comment: Since you specify "~$ at the beginning of the name", you might consider `grepl( "^~\\$", ch[1] )` to be more specific with the search.

Comment: Hi @akrun,@rosscova, am afraid grepl("\\$MS",ch[1]) returns incorrect result as well, so does grepl( "^~\\$", ch[1] )

Comment: @rosscova I have done earlier, but I think it got changed with Tim's edit